# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Perspective

Tags: php, mysql

Code:

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO book
     ( id
     , account_no
     , admin_id
     , title
     , author
     , edition
     , book_publisher
     , book_copies
     , book_isbn
     , print_place
     , book_year
     , book_pages
     , book_price
     , entry_date
     ) VALUES 
     ( ''
     , '$account_id'
     , '$admin_id'
     , '$title'
     , '$author'
     , '$edition'
     , '$publisher'
     , '$copies'
     , '$isbn'
     , '$place'
     , '$year'
     , '$pages'
     , '$price'
     , '$date'
)
";
```

While inserting data using this query I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Perspective','Randal E. Bryant','2','Prentice Hall','2','978-0136108047','USA'' at line 3

can anyone tell how to resolve this error?

Comment: Injection attacks still occur, and you are at risk

Comment: Obviously there's some value like `Someone's Perspective` which ruins query. Use PDO, prepared statements, escape data etc.

Comment: Are you sure the id column is not set to auto_increment in the database? If it is, exclude from both the tables, and the values list.

Comment: use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function for the variable which has value `'s Perspective` ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @TBI I think we've moved on from that. See prepared statements.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 The error is an unescaped apostrophe in a string which contains " 's Perspective ", E.g. " A Teacher's Perspective"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used this function of mysql to insert the value

> mysql_real_escape_string()

For Example:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
```

it worked...

Answer (score 1):

Name of the book "A Programmer's Perspective" contains "'" character, so you have to escape this variable with appropriate function:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-escape-string.php for example, in case of PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing `'` with `\"`. Sample for publisher field below. Just apply the same for other field which will have possible ' or ".

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO book
     ( id
     , account_no
     , admin_id
     , title
     , author
     , edition
     , book_publisher
     , book_copies
     , book_isbn
     , print_place
     , book_year
     , book_pages
     , book_price
     , entry_date
     ) VALUES 
     ( ''
     , '$account_id'
     , '$admin_id'
     , '$title'
     , '$author'
     , '$edition'
     , \"$publisher\"
     , '$copies'
     , '$isbn'
     , '$place'
     , '$year'
     , '$pages'
     , '$price'
     , '$date'
)
";
```

Answer (score -2):

try this without insert `id` value:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `book`
(`account_no`, `admin_id`, `title`, `author`, `edition`, `book_publisher`, `book_copies`, `book_isbn`, `print_place`, `book_year`, `book_pages`, `book_price`, `entry_date`) 
VALUES ('$account_id','$admin_id','$title','$author','$edition','$publisher','$copies','$isbn','$place','$year','$pages','$price','$date')";
```